How to Optimize COUNT Query on a Bugs on a large Table with Existing Index Constraints?
I’m working on a query to count the number of bugs created on 2019-03-01 or later from a bugs table with the following schema:
bugs(id, token, title, category, device, reported_at, created_at, updated_at) 
Here is the query I’m currently using:
SELECT COUNT(*)

FROM bugs

WHERE created_at >= '2019-03-01';

However, this query is running very slowly, and I am hitting time limits. I should mention that I can't add any new indexes to this table. There is an existing index named index_bugs_on_category_and_token_and_reported_at.
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to optimize this query or any alternative approaches to speed it up given the existing constraints.

If you don’t have an index on created_at that would speed it up, but only if your WHERE clause excludes a significant proportion of the table

Since you said you can't create a new index, then I'm afraid you're SOL on optimizing this query.  You could store the count in a cache and fetch it from that cached value when you need it quickly. Other than that, I suppose upgrading to a faster server might help a little. Or deleting most of your data. :-)

Please edit your question to show output of show create table bugs;

You can create a table where you store a record for each month in time and store the number of records in the given month, the minimum bug id in that month and the maximum bug id in that month, the structure would look like this:
monthly_bugs(id, started_at, ended_at, number_of_bugs)

And then if you want to get the number of bugs since a start of a month, you would do something like
select sum(number_of_bugs)
from monthly_bugs
where started_at >= '2019-03-01'

Sure, you will need to do large data imports at first, which takes time, but that's a once in a lifetime cost for you. Additionally, you could regularly add/update the newest month record as bugs are pouring in.

The problem is i can't modify the database due to some constraints

@MarkoSami this would be a new table, without modifying your existing database. I cannot help you unless you explain your constraints in a very detailed manner. My next solution would run into some other constraint and then the one afterwards would run into some further constraint. So please explain the constraints that you have, it would greatly help my thinking to know where the bounds are.

The problem was that it was a question on an assessment, and the database was read-only, so I couldn't create new indexes or tables. When I performed this query, I always received the "TIme limit exceeded" response. I wanted to know how to handle something like that because I think there's nothing more I can do here.
